# Enumerating Datatable rows in batches efficiently

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datatable

I'd like to enumerate through a datatable in batches. To do so, I've created a method which returns an `IEnumerable<DataTable>` That method looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<DataTable> EnumerateRowsInBatches( DataTable table, int batchSize ) {

    int rowCount = table.Rows.Count;
    int batchIndex = 0;
    while( batchIndex * batchSize < rowCount ) {
        DataTable result = table.Clone();
        int batchStart = batchIndex * batchSize;
        int batchLimit = ( batchIndex + 1 ) * batchSize;
        if( rowCount < batchLimit )
            batchLimit = rowCount;
        for( int i = batchStart; i < batchLimit; i++ ) {
            result.ImportRow( table.Rows[ i ] );
        }
        batchIndex++;
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

This works pretty nicely actually. I'm iterating through these batches in order to send to SQL Server using a Table Valued Parameter. but I'm seeing that the `ImportRow` is taking the majority of the elapsed time and I'd like to speed it up.

I'm looking for how to do that. I'm free to treat all data as read-only and so I get the sense that copying rows is not strictly necessary here.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't use `result.Rows.Add`?

Comment: Or a reason not to use [DataTable.AsEnumerable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Not particularly. I'll have to call it as often as ImportRow correct? Does that perform better (I'll have to measure it).

Comment: @MichaelJSwart: Yes, you would call it just as often as `ImportRow`. And yes, you need to measure it.

Comment: @Raidri I'm not using AsEnumerable because it returns a DataRow enumerable. I want a Datatable Enumerable

Comment: For the curious result.Rows.Add  will give a System.ArgumentException: "This row already belongs to another table." (cc @DanielHilgarth)

Comment: Can you thread your ImportRow call?

Comment: As whole point is to send data to a stored procedure, would an XML parameter fit in here?

Comment: @RubensFarias Yes, the point is to send to a stored procedure. But performance is important and I don't want to introduce xml processing on both the server and app side.

Comment: I don't know how you got those DataTables, but maybe you could to read your data as a DataReader (so you'll get only a record each time -- fast and memory wise) and build that suggest XML parameter (easy to transfer). Of course, large XML string could impact your performance, but I think is better than sending a data table. I usually send XML parameters and use a temp table at SQL server side.

Comment: @RubensFarias I have to disagree with you. TVPs generally perform much better than shredding xml parameters. http://sqlfool.com/2008/11/performance-comparison-of-singleton-xml-and-tvp-inserts/

Comment: @MichaelJSwart, you're right! I did my own tests and came with this results: TVP=3.48ms, XML=15.58ms, DML=40.75ms

Comment: @RubensFarias That's awesome thanks for letting me know and three cheers for data-backed discoveries!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came with an approach which lead to a ~40% performance improvement in my tests:

```
public static IEnumerable<DataTable> EnumerateRowsInBatches(DataTable table,
                                                            int batchSize)
{
    int rowCount = table.Rows.Count;
    int batchIndex = 0;
    DataTable result = table.Clone(); // This will not change, avoid recreate it
    while (batchIndex * batchSize < rowCount)
    {
        result.Rows.Clear(); // Reuse that DataTable, clear previous results
        int batchStart = batchIndex * batchSize;
        int batchLimit = (batchIndex + 1) * batchSize;
        if (rowCount < batchLimit)
            batchLimit = rowCount;

        for (int i = batchStart; i < batchLimit; i++)
            result.Rows.Add(table.Rows[i].ItemArray); // Avoid ImportRow

        batchIndex++;
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work for the OP's purpose, but in certain other situations re-using the same table and clearing rows can cause bad results.

Comment: Do you have an example of this situation, @JoelCoehoorn?

Comment: Compare two tables in this snippet: `var tables = EnumerateRowsInBatches(...).Take(2).ToList();` The code returns a reference to the _same_ object over and over. The state is different at each point, but if you wait until _after_ the enumeration to look at any results, every item is the same, and should match the last item enumerated.

Comment: Yes, this looks promising. In my case, the perf gains will likely be worth the trade-off of flexibility or robust.